# Replace using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I just want to remove `double quotes(")` of a string `"dropDownStorePrepare(this,\'hello\')"`.
Tried this way but not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = '"store":"dropDownStorePrepare(this,\'hello\')","name":"Rama Rao"';

$str =~ s/"dropDownStorePrepare(.*)"/dropDownStorePrepare$1/ig;

print $str;
```

Double quotes which are at the beginning and ending of the dropDownStorePrepare(,,,) should be removed and rest of the double quotes should be remained.

*Note:* dropDownStorePrepare function should accept any no of parameters.

Can somebody help me please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try non greedy regex,

```
$str =~ s/"dropDownStorePrepare(.*?)"/dropDownStorePrepare$1/ig;
```

Comment: @RamaRaoM you can shorten right side by capturing everything inside `$1`, _______________________ `$str =~ s/"(dropDownStorePrepare.*?)"/$1/ig;`

Comment: @mpapec But that won't do case normalization. (That might or might not be wanted.)

Comment: @DonalFellows yes, but it is also hard to tell whether normalization was intentional or accidental (I would say accidental judging from input string).

Answer (score 3):

The immediate problem you've got is that the `.*` is matching too much. Try:

```
$str =~ s/"dropDownStorePrepare(.*?)"/dropDownStorePrepare$1/ig;
```

Though it looks like you're trying to parse JSON. Maybe you should look for a [module](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm) to do that for you…